# Is possible to execute Stored Procedure MySQL Azure using apache beam in cloud dataflow google cloud platform?

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to execute Stored Procedure MySQL Azure using apache beam in cloud dataflow google cloud platform

Is possible to execute Stored Procedure MySQL Azure using apache beam in cloud dataflow google cloud platform?

If possible, how to execute Stored Procedure MySQL Azure using apache beam in cloud dataflow google cloud platform?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam provides a JDBC connector that allows you to connect to any Database that supports JDBC. I haven't tried MySQL on Azure [but seems like it supports JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/connect-java?tabs=passwordless). Please see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java) for the relavent Beam connector.